# Push array to the state using react hooks setstate not working

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have initialized the state `selectedProductList` as follows:

```
const [selectedProductList, setSelectedProductList] = useState([]);
```

On the return part: I have following snippet:

```
return (
    <>
        <Select
            id="product_id"
            name="product_id"
            onChange={handleProductSelection}
            // value={formData.product_id}
            value={products.filter(function (option) {
                return option.value === formData.product_id;
            })}
            options={products}
            className={` ${
                errors["product_id"] ? "is-invalid" : ""
            }`}
        />
        {selectedProductList.map((item) => {
            {
                console.log("called");
                item != undefined && (
                    <tr key={item.product_id}>
                        <td>{item.product_id}</td>
                    </tr>
                );
            }

            // <SelectedProductList repeatedRow={} errors/>;
        })}

    </>
)
```

Here, `<Select/>` is the react select component, and on change it is firing `handleProductSelection` event.
And, to handle this selection scenario, I have:

```
const handleProductSelection = (event) => {
    console.log("handle selection>> " + event);
    const { name, value, label } = event;
    console.log("handle selection>> " + value);
    var newProductArr = [];
    newProductArr[value] = [];
    newProductArr[value]["product_id"] = value;
    newProductArr[value]["quantity"] = "";
    newProductArr[value]["unit_id"] = "";
    newProductArr[value]["price_per_unit"] = "";
    setSelectedProductList((selectedProductList) => [
        ...selectedProductList,
        ...newProductArr,
    ]);
};

useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selectedProductList >>", selectedProductList);
}, [selectedProductList]);
```

Here, whenever I change the select list it is consoling the value as:

[image]

However, If I look at the components tab it is showing as `[undefined,undefined,[],undefined,undefined,undefined,[]]`

Comment: How / where did you define `products`?

Comment: products is the props which consists array or products. that select part is showing the options correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you want to define a new product as an array? This seems more correct:

```
var newProduct = {};
newProduct["product_id"] = value;
newProduct["quantity"] = "";
newProduct["unit_id"] = "";
newProduct["price_per_unit"] = "";
setSelectedProductList((selectedProductList) => [
    ...selectedProductList,
    newProduct,
]);
```

**Edit**

Your you've defined the callback function passed to `map()` as `(item) => { /* ... */ }`. Such syntax expects a `return` statement:

```
{selectedProductList.map((item) => {
  console.log("called");
  return (
    item != undefined && (
      <tr key={item.product_id}>
        <td>{item.product_id}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  );
})}
```

Note that while this works, a good linter/formatter (ESLint, Prettier) will still complain about this code. I highly recommend you embed either one of those into your IDE!

As per inlining conditionals that yield JSX, you have two options:

- [**Inline If with Logical && Operator**](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)
- [**Inline If-Else with Conditional Operator**](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator)